# Tcl: on the fly command substuition

Tags: tcl

I have the following code which based on the variable `op` invokes either `min` or `max`.

```
  switch $op {
      min {
        set x  [::tcl::mathfunc::min {*}$lax]
        set y  [::tcl::mathfunc::min {*}$lay]
      }
      max {
        set x  [::tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$lax]
        set y  [::tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$lay]
      }
  }
```

Instead of writing it through a switch, I want to write something like the following.

```
       set x  [::tcl::mathfunc::$op {*}$lax]
       set y  [::tcl::mathfunc::$op {*}$lay]
```

I tried using `subst` command but could not get it to work. I use `Tcl 8.5.7`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example should work unmodified, so no need to over-engeneer.
Observe:

```
% set lax {1 2 3}
1 2 3
% set op min
min
% set x [::tcl::mathfunc::$op {*}$lax]
1
% set op max
max
% set x [::tcl::mathfunc::$op {*}$lax]
3
```

Comment: Works for me as is also in 8.5.9

Comment: @Niall: This will work in anything from 8.5.0 onwards. Before that, there wasn't `{*}` syntax _or_ the min and max functions…